# Selecting the row from table with equal colum values but newest date

Tags: mysql, date, delete-row

I have got a table with rows having the same kundennummer and same artikelnummer but not the same date. I want to delete all rows which do not have the newest date.
I have tried the whole evening with delete and insert.
Now i try to create a new table with this values. Kundennummer,

db0

```
kundennummer, artikelnummer, date,price  
'11002', '00000010', '2013-07-04', 4.20 ''  
'11002', '00000010', '2013-07-08', 4.13 ''<-- this as result  
'33002', '00000020', '2013-07-04', 1.80 ''  
'33002', '00000020', '2013-07-18', 1.60 ''<--and this as result
```

```
insert db1 (Kundennummer, Artikelnummer, Date, price)
select Kundennummer, Artikelnummer, max(date) as date, price 
from db0
where kundennummer = kundennummer
and artikelnummer = artikelnummer;
```

The result is only one row.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You want to add "GROUP BY artikelnummer" so you get values for each article.

Comment: Thanks a lot it seems to work with this additional two lines:

    GROUP BY artikelnummer
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE artikelnummer = artikelnummer;

Thanks, it took me all the evening and you 5 minutes.